# Explicit formula for $S(t)$ in SIR model

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I have been trying to formulate the general equation for the number of susceptibles in the compartmental model for an epidemic where S(t) is the number of susceptibles, I(t) is the number of infectives and R(t) is the number of those who have been recovered all at time t. The equations are:

\begin{align*}
&\frac{dS}{dt} = -\beta S(t)I(t)\quad or\quad -\beta SI\\
&\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta SI-\gamma I\\
&\frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma I\\
\end{align*}
For solving $I(t)$, I took
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{dI}{dS} = \dfrac{dI/dt}{dS/dt}\\
\mbox{i.e.,} \qquad &\frac{dI}{dS} = \frac{\beta SI-\gamma I}{-\beta SI}=-\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta S}\right)=\frac{\gamma}{\beta S}-1\\
\end{align*}
After separating the variables, $dI=\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\beta S}-1\right)dS$

By integrating both sides, we get $I(t)=\dfrac{\gamma}{\beta}lnS - S + C$

where C is an integration constant

If  $I(0)=i_0$ and $S(0)=s_0$, then
\begin{align*}
&i_0 = \dfrac{\gamma}{\beta}lns_0-s_0+C\\
∴\ &C = i_0-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}lns_0+s_0\\
\implies\ \ &I(t) = \frac{\gamma}{\beta}(lnS-lns_0)-(S-s_0)+i_0\\
&\quad \ \ =\frac{\gamma}{\beta}ln\left(\frac{S}{s_0}\right)-(S-s_0)+i_0\\
\end{align*}
The problem is when I put this value in $\dfrac{dS}{dt} = -\beta SI$
\begin{align*}
&\mbox{i.e., }\qquad \frac{dS}{dt}=-\beta S\left(\frac{\gamma}{\beta}ln\left(\frac{S}{s_0}\right)-(S-s_0)+i_0\right)\\
&\qquad \qquad \quad \ =-\gamma S\ln\left(\frac{S}{s_0}\right)+\beta S(S-s_0)-\beta Si_0\\
\end{align*}
After rearranging and integrating both sides,

$\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{dS}{-\gamma S\ln\left(\dfrac{S}{s_0}\right)+\beta S(S-s_0)-\beta Si_0}} =\int dt $

After which, I don't know what to do. Please tell me what is wrong here and also write the correct method.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no explicit formula for $S(t)$ alone. The best one can do is to "solve" the last expression you gave, saying that $S(t)$ is such that $$\int_{S(t)}^{s_0}\frac{du}{u\cdot(\gamma \ln\left(u/s_0\right)+\beta (i_0+s_0-u))}=t$$

Comment: ((Your formatting is rather weird... Please have a look at the source of other questions on the site, to avoid that most of your text ends up being written in math mode.))

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know how to check the source code of questions. By math mode, do you mean the italic format in which my statements in between the equations are written?

Comment: Also, please explain how the integration is from S(t) to $s_0$. Thanks

Comment: "how the integration is from S(t) to s0" Watch for the change of sign in the parenthesis.